# Georeferencing, Scaling Sentinel 5P data

Tags: qgis, sentinel-5p

I have a sentinel 5P data downloaded from here https://s5phub.copernicus.eu/dhus it is a **.nc** file that includes many things in it.

**S5P_OFFL_L2__O3_____20220129T103157_20220129T121327_22261_02_020201_20220131T024607**

I am pretty new to QGIS and I don't know why this happens and how to solve it. I want the data should be seen somewhere on the open street map, where it should be. The .nc file includes product latitude and longitude information but I don't find how to use them.

The photo can be explaining better. [image]

similar to this question but the answer is not satisfying [ESA Sentinel-5 data in QGIS: "invalid projection"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409038/esa-sentinel-5-data-in-qgis-invalid-projection)

Comment: It says there in the layer name that this is an image of the vertical ozone distribution.

Comment: yes .nc file includes many information and among them, I need to use vertical ozone distribution. @Erik

Comment: And how do you expect QGIS to visualize this data?

Comment: Actually, this was the only way that I was able to open the netCDF file. If you have any other suggestions, it would be perfect as well. Maybe I am on the wrong way in the beginning.

Comment: What I am trying to point out: QGIS displays two dimensional data (coordinate pairs) with other dimensions as attributes. You try to load three dimensional data. That wont work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using Google Earth Engine for data acquisition.

They have S5 data here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_O3

They provide an example script here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=Examples%3ADatasets%2FCOPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_O3

You can define the output projection for your data with the `crs` argument in the  `Export.image.toDrive()` function. The file will also be delivered to your google drive as a .tif, which means no need to deal with issues related to using .nc files.